# How to set css background image from byte array saved in database

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Using ASP.NET MVC5 I know I can simply load the source of an image tag from the controller like so:

```
<img class="img-thumbnail" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new { Model.ProductId })" />
```

With the controller returning `FileContentResult`

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int productId) {
    Product prod = repository.Products
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
    if (prod != null) {
        // ImageData is the byte array
        return File(prod.ImageData, prod.ImageMimeType);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My View, however, requires the image be loaded as the CSS Background of the div:

```
<div class="mdl-card__media mdl-color-text--grey-50" style="padding-left: 10px; height:274px; background: url('@Model.ImagePath;')">
```

The ImagePath value isn't saving correctly, using an absolute path of `E:\Development\ortund\blog\blog\Content\Images\uploads\{filename}`

The byte array, however, is being saved correctly.

Can I use the `@Url.Action()` method to load the byte array of the image into the css and render the image that way?

If not, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Action()` isn't the way to go on this one.

Instead, I converted the image byte array in the database to a base64 string which I then used for the background:

```
<div style="background: url(data:@Model.ImageMimeType;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image) )"></div>
```